# INSERTAR Array a BBDD desde PHP

Tags: php, array, mysqli, insert

Intento añadir a la base de datos un Array Serializado, para almacenar imágenes de un producto, el caso es que en la base de datos me almacena como "Array", y no el Array en sí.

Esto es lo que estoy intentando:

```
$img = array(
    "url" => $img_princip,
    "alt" => $alt_img_princip
);

serialize($img);
```

¿Alguien ha trabajado esto alguna vez, y puede ayudarme? Muchas gracias de ante mano.

Comment: No entiendo. ¿Quieres guardar un array en una columna de la base de datos? Si es eso, ¿por qué quieres hacer eso y no organizas mejor, creando por ejemplo una columnas para `url` y otra para `alt`? ¿Cómo está constituida la tabla con la que estás trabajando?

Comment: No quiero una columna para url, y otra para alt, ya que hay productos que pueden tener 20 imágenes, de ahí a simplificarlo a un Array. (sería una exageración crear esas columnas) . En cuanto la tabla, el campo imágenes, es un campo VARCHAR.

Comment: No tengo una visión global de tu modelo de datos, pero tengo la impresión de que haciendo esto no simplificas nada, sino que más bien lo complicas. Por ejemplo si el valor de `$img_princip` es un valor repetitivo, y el valor de `$alt_img_princip` también, lo correcto es que hagas una normalización que puede ser incluso más profunda: creando una tabla `url` y otra tabla `alt` y allí insertes de manera única cada `url` y cada `alt`. Luego usas los ID para asignarlos a cada elemento que use esa `url` y ese `alt`. Como digo, no creo que simplificas intentando guardar un array, sino que complicas.

Comment: Me aconsejas, crear una tabla, que sea imágenes, (id_img, id_prod, url, alt) y utilizar esta tabla exclusiva para las imágenes. ¿Me equivoco? Si es así, si sería una alternativa, pero me pareció más ""simple"" guardarlo como array serialize en una columna.

Comment: No solamente eso, si quieres normalizar de verdad debes plantearte un objetivo: que no haya dos valores que se repitan, por ejemplo, dos `url` o dos `alt`... Para eso, tendrías que tener cuatro tablas: `tabla_url (id_url, url), tabla_alt (id_alt, alt), tabla_imagen (id_img, id_url, id_alt), tabla_producto (id_prod, id_img)` ... entonces en `tabla_imagen` guardar bajo una restricción `UNIQUE` los id de la url y del alt y en `tabla_producto` usas el `id_img` para obtener los valores respectivos. Con ese modelo evitas redundancia de datos y cualquier evolución no será una catástrofe.

Comment: ... si es al revés, que `N` productos pueden tener `N` imágenes, entonces hace falta una modificación: `tabla_producto` quedaría así: `tabla_producto(id_prod, ...resto de columnas propias de productos)` y recurres a una tabla asociativa donde pones en relación los productos y las imágenes: `producto_imagen(id_prod, id_img)` con una restricción `UNIQUE`. En esa tabla irá por cada fila las imágenes diversas que tenga un producto. O sea, `id_img` no iría en la `tabla_prod` (porque un mismo producto puede tener varias imágenes) y trasladas la relación a otra tabla.

Comment: Veo bastante viable, la opción de separar la tabla de imágenes (como dices en el último comentario añadido). Aunque no me preocupa el tema de duplicidad de imágenes, ya que lo controlo mediante subida ftp a carpeta /images. El problema de este método, que complica un poco más la consulta a la hora de mostrar productos. De ahí que me gustara más el Array.

Comment: Mmmm no, no complica nada, se trata de escribir una consulta uniendo cada tabla relacionada mediante `JOIN`. La consulta te traería exactamente los datos que necesitas (que en tu modelo estarían todos apiñados en un array) y en el otro modelo estaría debidamente organizados y además indexados. Con que en la fila uno tengas la url `imagen-amarilla.jpg` como un elemento del array y en la fila 99999 tengas otro array con el valor `imagen-amarilla.jpg` ¡ya tienes redundancia de datos!.

Comment: Me ha convencido esta idea, ya que me a dado otras ideas, para crear un gestor de imágenes en el sitio, bastante fácil de administrar (mejor que con los Array) Así que ya estoy manos a la obra. Muchas gracias A.Cedano por tu ayuda y consejo para mejorar :)

Comment: De nada. Y si hay alguna duda la puedes plantear aquí donde podrás tener el punto de vista de uno o más usuarios que te ayudarán a resolver el problema o a replantearlo de una mejor manera. Saludos.